# css settings for fitting two blocks in same line

Tags: css

I am trying to set two consecutive lines in one line by using negative padding or negative margin. But for correct positioning i have been setting fixed margins which distort everything then the resolution is changed. The link to the website is [www.ideas2ignite.com/wordpress](http://www.ideas2ignite.com/wordpress). I have tried fitting two blocks in one line using table but couldn't. If anybody could suggest me how to go about setting this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which blocks on that page are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably may want to make an unordered list that contains those two consecutive items, so you have

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

Next thing you want to do is to wrap them inside a `div`, and then in your css file, set the `<li>` float attribute to be `float:left;` This way, they will appear next to each other without needing of negative padding/numerical positional adjustment.

Comment: I have made these changes successfully but only one thing that is messing up is the 4 social networking icons in the header navigation bar. It is appearing in one line in all browsers except IE8. Its a list but don't know even after making all the elements with float:left couldn't get all in one line.
You may save my another hour.

Comment: dont forget to set the width of the element, and also you have to be careful, if you set float:left on one element, then the element proceeding it will also be affected by the flow..to avoid that, set clear:both on that proceeding element.